# Cannot connect to FTPS at the same machine

Tags: windows-10, filezilla, winscp, ftps

I need to create FTPS server for code testing purpose. I did such thing in IIS on port 990, generated a self-signed certificate and tried to connect via WinSCP at the same machine (All programs hosted locally). I created new session with my machine IP, username, 990 port number, chose FTP protocol, implicit encryption TLS/SSL and input my test password.

When I try to login I get communicate "Tls connection established waiting for welcome message" and a password prompt appears. After entering the test password I get only "Access denied" and nothing else.

When I tried do the same in filezilla I got only 
"Connecting to server [myIp]:990...
Connected, waiting for authentication
Connection to server closed.
Trying to reconnect in 5 seconds" repeatedly.

My machine's operating system is Windows 10. Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? This is my log file after my login attempt:

```
`. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.256 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.256 WinSCP Wersja 5.15.1 (Build 9407) (OS 10.0.18362 - Windows 10 Enterprise)
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.256 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.256 Log level: Normal
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.256 Local account: XXXXXX
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.256 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.256 Process ID: 11024
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Time zone: Current: GMT+2, Standard: GMT+1 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.), DST: GMT+2 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni), DST Start: 31.03.2019, DST End: 27.10.2019
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Login time: poniedziałek, 17 czerwiec 2019 17:24:59
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Session name: user@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx (Site)
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Host name: xx.xx.xx.xxx (Port: 990)
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 User name: user (Password: No, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Transfer Protocol: FTP
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Ping type: Dummy, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Disable Nagle: No
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Proxy: None
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Send buffer: 262144
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 UTF: Auto
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 FTPS: Implicit TLS/SSL [Client certificate: No]
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 FTP: Passive: Yes [Force IP: Auto]; MLSD: Auto [List all: Auto]; HOST: Auto
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Session reuse: Yes
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 TLS/SSL versions: TLSv1.0-TLSv1.2
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Local directory: default, Remote directory: C:\ftpstest, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 Timezone offset: 0h 0m
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.257 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.321 Połączanie do xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:990...
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.321 Połączono z xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:990, negocjowanie połączenia TLS...
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.321 Verifying certificate for "" with fingerprint 7e:ea:df:4b:d7:47:0e:92:b9:37:b6:a0:05:03:3e:89:90:86:50:a8 and 20 failures
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.321 Certificate for "" matches cached fingerprint and failures
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.321 Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3: AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA, AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
. 2019-06-17 17:24:59.342 Połączenie TLS nawiązane. Czekam na wiadomość powitalną...
< 2019-06-17 17:24:59.342 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> 2019-06-17 17:24:59.342 USER user
< 2019-06-17 17:24:59.342 331 Password required
> 2019-06-17 17:25:03.247 PASS ***
< 2019-06-17 17:25:03.584 530-User cannot log in.
< 2019-06-17 17:25:03.584  Win32 error:   
< 2019-06-17 17:25:03.584  Error details: An error occurred during the authentication process.
< 2019-06-17 17:25:03.584 530 End
. 2019-06-17 17:25:03.584 Połączenie nie powiodło się.
. 2019-06-17 17:25:03.606 Password prompt (last login attempt failed)`
```

Comment: Are you using active of passive mode to connect? Try the other mode as test.

Comment: @harrymc It does not look like the the connection got to a point, where passive/active mode would matter.

Comment: @piotreqd Show us WinSCP session log file.

Comment: To the poster : I suggest doing as advised by @MartinPrikryl, who is the best authority on the subject.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl done.

Comment: So you **can connect** - You cannot authenticate. What credentials are you using?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl In WinScp I entered FTP implicit encryption TLS/SSL my IP adress, 990 - port number the same as in my FTP server configuration, my username and password. When I try to login I use password created in previous step.

Comment: Created is **what** previous step?

Comment: In session creating

Comment: @MartinPrikryl like this : https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/6793/k4DMuQ.jpg

Comment: Entering credentials on WinSCP **login** dialog does not create the account. That would even make no sense. If it were possible, anyone could login to your server!?!

Comment: You have to use your Windows credentials.